# Script that randomly choose a sound to reproduce when I click on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to be able to click on an image and get a random sound reproduced between the sounds I put in a folder on my server.

Actually my code is like this, clicking on the image will reproduce only AUDIO_SRC.

```
<audio id="ID" src="AUDIO_SRC" preload="auto"></audio>

<a href="javascript:play_sound();">
<img src='IMG_SRC' style="display: block;" alt=""  width="60%" height="60%">
</a>

<script type="text/javascript"> function play_sound() { document.getElementById('ID').play(); } </script>
```

The script should be able to pick a random sound from the folder /bf and reproduce it.

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, this is very possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: And how would your JS code know which files are in the folder `bf`. JavaScript is ran on the clients pc and isn't allowed to retrieve the files in that folder, you will need server side scripting for that.

Comment: Have a look at the [.random() JS function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp), might help you in the right direction! Hint: Might help you get an random ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can type the audio files into an array or use ajax to call some server-side code to return all audio files within your directory but to keep the answer as simple as the question asked.

```
//Array of audio files
var MyList=['Audio1.mp3','Audio2.mp3','Audio3.mp3','Audio4.mp3','Audio5.mp3'];
    function randomPlay(){
//Get player by id
    var a=document.getElementById('Player');
//Select random array.
    var playNow = MyList[Math.floor(Math.random() * MyList.length)];
//Set new src
    a.src="http://yourdomain.com/bf/"+playNow;
//Play audio
    a.play();
    }
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding!